# Maven cannot find pom.xml in Jenkins workspace

Tags: maven, jenkins, pom.xml

I have a problem using Jenkins.

In the job configuration, I defined the svn-repository as

```
svn://localhost/home/svn-repository/testRepo/branches/develop/
```

and everything works fine. Jenkins checks the repository out in its own workspace which looks like this:

```
workspace
  |-- pom.xml
  |-- src
       |-- ...
```

and the maven-goals are successfully executed.
But if I set the root directory of the repository (because I want Jenkins to check out the latest revision of the project, not of an special branch), maven cannot find the pom.xml.

```
svn://localhost/home/svn-repository/testRepo/
```

The Jenkins workspace in this case is:

```
workspace
  |-- branches
        |-- develop
              |-- pom.xml
              |-- src
                   |-- ...
```

Comment: Your structure in SVN is wrong. `project/trunk`, `project/tags`, `project/branches` should be the structure. and for the default `trunk` you should checkout the trunk which means `project/trunk` into your workspace.

Comment: try to add a shell command in jenkins job `pwd` to see from which directory it is trying to execute the job and set the pom.xml path relatively

Comment: The error message of the job says "Goal requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/TestJob/workspace).". So Maven obviously tries to read the pom.xml out of this directory.

Comment: Is there a possibility to tell Maven to search also in the subdirectories of the workspace?

Comment: Yes - where you enter the maven goals you could enter `-f branches/develop/pom.xml` to tell maven what POM to use.  But really, @khmarbraise advise is the best, you should use a `project/trunk` dir for the latest revision of the dir, and just check out that.  If you want to sometimes build from trunk and sometimes from a branch then you could parameterise the jenkins job and with the http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin you can add a "List subverion tags" parameter that will allow you to choose from trunk or one of the branches or tags.

Answer (score 2):

In the *Build* section you have an input field *Root POM* where you can add the (relative) path to your pom file, for example `testRepo/trunk/pom.xml`.

Not sure why you don't limit your checkout to the specific path you want to build tough. In contrast to Git (where you'd have a different project structure), this is trivial with SVN.

Comment: I didn´t want to use a specific path, because maybe there are several branches, and i wanted Jenkins to checkout the latest revision which could be in any of these. But i see it makes no sence. Thanks